# Create log for asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to create a log file for a asp.net web application. Could you help me to create it. I want to monitor the each and every action about my application.

Comment: We need more info than this. Add a little bit of your code and tell us what this application is supposed to do .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use log4net i think.It helps you so log4Net works, performs well and is stable

Take a look this samples :

[Log4Net Imlementing](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2012/04/16/using-log4net-in-an-asp-net-application.aspx)

[Log4Net Sample 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37107/Log4Net-with-ASP-NET-3-5-File-Appender)

Answer (score 0):

3rd party frameworks like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) and [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) would really help you. Here are some tutorials: [log4net tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial) and [NLog tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10631/Introduction-to-NLog). Relying on logs may not be the best idea though - it really depends on the application you're creating. An audit table could be more suitable.